# How to make eclipse Luna compile with debug information?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using java8 with eclipse Luna on Ubuntu. And I checked all the options under

> Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler->Classfile Generation

but eclipse still don't generate line number and I can't debug on my own code. Does anybody know another settings somewhere that can fix this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: are you sure that your project uses the settings from the Preferences section and has no own project-specific settings?

Comment: I am not sure if it has its own settings. Where to check for that?

Comment: Thanks mschenk74 for pointing out the project-specific settings, it turns out that the line number is unchecked for my project at Project --> Build Path -> Configure Build Path --> Compiler. If you make it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that your project doesn't use the settings from Preferences and has project specific settings instead.

If you right-click on the project and then select *"Properties"->"Java Compiler"* you can see the line *"Enable project specific settings"* on the top.

If this checkbox is checked, then you have project specific settings, otherwise the settings from Preferences will be used.